How is the proper way to migrate a SignalR Azure Function from in process .NET 6 to isolated worker .NET8?
I could not find examples of how to replace some of the classes and attributes of SignalR that has changed from in process .NET 6 Azure Functions to isolated ones in .NET 8.
Examples:
[Function("negotiate")]    
public async Task<IActionResult> Negotiate(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")]HttpRequest req, 
    IBinder binder
)
{
    AuthenticationResult result = await _validation.ValidateTokenAsync(req);

    string? email = req.TryGetEmail(_logger);

    if (result.IsInvalid() || string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
    {
        return new UnauthorizedResult();
    }

    var connectionInfo = await binder.BindAsync<SignalRConnectionInfo>(new SignalRConnectionInfoAttribute
    {
        HubName = HikyakuConstants.DefaultHubName,
        UserId = email,
    });

    return new OkObjectResult(connectionInfo);
}

In the code above, IBinder works greatly in .NET6, but in .net 8 isolated it should not be used. Also, as I'm getting the UserId from the email, which is inside auth token in req, I cannot use the new way of getting it like this:
 [Function("negotiate")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Negotiate(
     [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")]
     HttpRequest req,
     [SignalRConnectionInfoInput(HubName = HikyakuConstants.DefaultHubName, UserId = "{headers.x-ms-client-principal-id}")]
     string connectionInfo)
 { ... }

Because I have not the email of the user set in headers.x-ms-client-principal-id nor headers.x-ms-client-principal-name.
This is one of my problems. I don't even know how to express the others. Maybe solving this one puts me in the right direction to solve the others.
Has anybody suffered a similar issue migrating AZ Functions that uses SignalR bindings and know how to approach them?
Obs.: The function is not written as FunctionName because I already did a lot of steps of the migrating process. Now it's the fine tunning (and the hardest) part of it.

thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I ended up choosing a different path, described here and with examples here the code became like this:
[Function("negotiate")]    
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Negotiate(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequestData reqData
)
{    
    AuthenticationResult result = await _validation.ValidateTokenAsync(req);

    string? email = reqData.TryGetEmail(_logger);

    if (result.IsInvalid() || string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
    {
        return reqData.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }

    NegotiationOptions options = new()
    {
        UserId = email,
    };

    var negotiateResponse = await NegotiateAsync(options);
    var response = reqData.CreateResponse();
    await response.WriteBytesAsync(negotiateResponse.ToArray());
    return response;
}

Now, I'm having problems with send message, since it is still an httptrigger, not a signalRtrigger as in the examples. But I'm trying to figure it out. Thanks anyway.
